# ATtiny402 ADC value comming not properly

Tags: c, avr, attiny

In ATtiny402 There is no increment ADC value when its came on +2.5v. Its stuck on that max adc value of when it reaches the corresponding +2.5v....there is no change even i adjust the trimpot above 2.5v. And here is code.

```
#include <avr/io.h> #include <util/delay.h> uint16_t volatile adcVal;

void ADC0_init(void); uint16_t ADC0_read(void);

void ADC0_init(void) { /* Disable digital input buffer */ PORTA.PIN6CTRL &= ~PORT_ISC_gm; PORTA.PIN6CTRL |= PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc;

  /* Disable pull-up resistor */
PORTA.PIN6CTRL &= ~PORT_PULLUPEN_bm;


ADC0.CTRLB = VREF_ADC0REFEN_bm ;
VREF.CTRLA = VREF_ADC0REFSEL_1_bm;  


ADC0.CTRLC |= ADC_PRESC_DIV4_gc      /* CLK_PER divided by 4 */
           | ADC_REFSEL_INTREF_gc;  /* Internal reference */


ADC0.CTRLA |= ADC_ENABLE_bm          /* ADC Enable: enabled */
           | ADC_RESSEL_10BIT_gc;   /* 10-bit mode */

/* Select ADC channel */
ADC0.MUXPOS  = ADC_MUXPOS_AIN6_gc;

}

uint16_t ADC0_read(void) { /* Start ADC conversion */ ADC0.COMMAND = ADC_STCONV_bm;

/* Wait until ADC conversion done */
while ( !(ADC0.INTFLAGS & ADC_RESRDY_bm) )
{
    ;
}

/* Clear the interrupt flag by writing 1: */
ADC0.INTFLAGS = ADC_RESRDY_bm;
return ADC0.RES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This writes a mask with bit ADC0REFSEL_1 set and enables 2.5V reference voltage.

```
VREF.CTRLA = VREF_ADC0REFSEL_1_bm;
```

ADC can't measure voltages above the reference.
Try different value or enable VDD as a reference on `ADC0.CTRLC`

Comment: You may also blow up the ADC by feeding it voltages much higher than the Vref.

Comment: i have changed as you said ,,but still there is something issues..the output comes as adc value = 0 when the 0v of input and adc value get higher and went greater than 1024 value when the input even 0.5v

Comment: @ashwinÃmani Please check the ATtiny402 datasheet and your code carefully. Internal reference can provide 0.55V (`VREF.CTRLA` on default state, `ADC0REFSEL[2:0] == 0`). Looks like `ADC0.CTRLC` is configured for internal reference and `VREF.CTRLA` for 0.55V

Comment: @ReAl Thank you sir...and had changed something...after that those issues are solved...even after there some doubts..please clarify me...i will post that current code

Comment: i got a decimal value 4092 without this `(ADC0.RES >> 2)`...after i did this 2 bit right shift i got 1024...i dont understand what exactly going on...is right shift essential for getting 1024.....and why is that working in only after 2 bit shifting...please explain me....@ReAl

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second question in the comment.

> I got a decimal value 4092 without this (ADC0.RES >> 2) … and why is that working in only after 2 bit shifting

The answer is to long to put it into a comment.
You have a mistake here using `ADC0.CTRLB` instead of `VREF.CTRLB`

```
ADC0.CTRLB = VREF_ADC0REFEN_bm;
```

So `VREF_ADC0REFEN_bm` which equal `2` is written into `SAMPNUM` ADC control field and `ACC4` mode is enabled. This means at every ADC conversion request it makes *four* conversions by itself and places the *sum* into ADC result register. So you should divide the result by 4 to have what you expected.

VREF works anyway because (absent) line

```
VREF.CTRLB = VREF_ADC0REFEN_bm;
```

just sets *permanent* enabling of ADC0REF output. Without this code line the output is enabled automatically by ADC request which requires more setup time though.

Comment: Hi Sir..im manikandan..from india....im new to embedded systems...i have some doubts and queries in embedded systems...will you please help me to get clarification...kindly share your email id please

Comment: Hi @manis. I’m sorry, I have no time to provide such support/mentoring by email. It would be better for you to ask Stack Overflow. If I have time, I answer. And someone else can answer too.